# Змей Горыныч — откуда он?

Tags: этимология

А вот интересно: ***откуда*** происходит имя сказочного **Змея Горыныча**?

От слова **"гореть"**? — Змей, вроде как, огнедышащий.
Или от слова **"гора"**?  — по легендам он жил где-то на территории современного Киева, в горе.

Или не то и не другое?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Хороший вопрос!
Скорее всего, напрямую  — ни то, ни другое.

От **горы** было бы **Горич**, а от глаголов притяжательные прилагательные, к которым восходят современные отчества, не образуются. А если и образуются, то через существительные.
Такие существительные  — в свою очередь  — образуются через субстантивирующий суффикс **-ун-** (пестун, болтун), но никак не через **-ын-**, т.е. от **"гореть"** было бы **Горун** и, стало быть, **Горуныч**.

Таким образом, совершенно очевидно, что **Горыныч**  — образование от собственного имени **Горыня**, по образцу **Добрыня**.

Вопрос, тем не менее, не снимается. Хочется понять, от чего же может быть образован этот Горыня? Ответ прост  — имя принадлежало одному из трёх богатырей-великанов славянской мифологии: Горыня, Дубыня и Усыня. Эти три тогдашних "авторитета" крепко безобразничали в древности, одного куража ради нарушая естественное течение жизни: сдвигали горы, выламывали леса, пускали вспять реки.
Вся доступная славянам наземная природа была строго поделена на сферы влияния между "братками": первый,  **Горыня**, специализировался как раз по горам; второй,  **Дубыня** (от "дуб", "дубы" в значении "дубрава"), куролесил в лесах; третий, **Усыня** (от "усы"  — река с притоками), отвечал за водные объекты.

**Змеи** проходили по ведомству первого, **Горыни**. Таким образом, в первооснове всё-таки  — гора, но не напрямую, а по ***принадлежности к клану.***

Answer (score 1):

Есть подозрение, что **Горыныч**  — от слова *"гореть"* или от слова *"жар"* (что, в сущности, одно и то же).

Comment: Мне с детства казалось, что змей зовётся *Горынычем* потому, что когда у него огонь из пасти вылетает, то от этого может что-то *загореться*.

Точного ответа почему -- Горыныч, я не знаю, и судить не берусь.

Answer (score 1):

Горыныч - от слова "гора". Слово "гора" во многих славянских языках означает "лес", а "горыныч", следовательно, - "лесной". Живая вода. Сборник русских народных песен, сказок, пословиц и загадок. Изд. 2-е. стр. 293

Comment: >Слово "гора" во многих славянских языках означает "лес", 

В каких конкретно, не назовете?
Кроме болгарского?

Comment: В языках родственных болгарскому - македонском, сербском, хорватском "гора" означает "лес".  Но Змей Горыныч - персонаж не болгарских, а русских сказок.  Так что и происхождение надо искать в русском языке.

Answer (score -1):

**@behemothus** прав: **ГОРЫНЫЧ**  — это отчество, образованное от имени типа ГОРИН или ГОРЫНЯ. Происхождение фольклорного образа **Змея Горыныча**  может быть и славянским, и хазарским, проникшим в русский фольклор. Во втором случае — это имя однозначно ивритное, но и в первом случае оно также может быть ивритным. Ивритные имена получили распространение на Руси вместе с христианской верой, которая первоначально пришла из Болгарии, а затем утвердилась в византийской традиции. Так, первые русские святые — братья Борис и Глеб, — оба носили ивритные имена, однако, совсем необязательно, что этнически они были евреями, а не славянами. Ниже я помещаю скриншот по интернет-ссылке [ЭКПВЕ - Го](http://jmemory.org/)                 ========================================================================= 
 [image: ЭКПВЕ - Главная]
[image: ЭКПВН-Мемориал-ГОРИН]

Answer (score -1):

Горыныч роисходит от Гора...Персонаж из сказок, а значит культовый...См термин Гора берет начало в ирнских и состоит из Гоу-Обитель и Ра-свет(свет в смысле не видимый, тайный, культовый, то что сегодня бы назвали энергия)... Т это полностью соответствует тому какое место занимают Горы вообще в культх до Хритианских... Горы почитаются как места обитания высших сил, Богов...Но почему Змей пылающий огнем и еще с тремя головами...твет можно найти у Скифо-Сармат которые почитали образ дракона как Мать Землю, т.е. это был образ матери земли... Тут они не оригинальны, потому как в древнем мире Богини-Роженицы часто изображаются либо Змеями, либо другими рептилиями, а часто Змеедевами... Но Скифо-Сарматы зовут себя Дурагон(Дракон на Европейский лад)... Суть в том что Дурагон буквально означает Дитя Горы... Т.е. Дракон и Горыныч это одно и то же... Но Горыныч трехглавый... И он в сказке экзаменует инициируемого-Ивана Дурака(Дараг-каменный)... Три головы это иносказательный образ трех ступеней восхождения культа мужской силы и знания... Иван проходит экзамен ответив на воапросы и получает Меч-кладенец... Мечь же в старинных культах ассоциируется с Мудростью... Т.е. Иван получает диплом, свидетельство об усвоенном материале говоря современным языком...Вывод здесь может быть тлько один : Горыныч это образ некоего знания, мудрости хронимой в Обители Света-в Горе... Это те самые сокровища охраняемые Драконом в европейских сказках... А Гора это та самая Мировая гора, Ось Мира-Меру, Мара,... как центр хранения Знаний, Мудрости, Силы... Это та самая Гора Алатырь из Славянской мифологии...

Comment: Опять за рыбу гроши... Аслан Бураев, что тут можно взять за основу происхождения? И как вы объясните происхождение Горыныч - от гора, а не от Горыня? Тут же не вечер литературной пародии, хочется обозреть конкретный ответ, объясняющий именно происхождение, этимологию слова.

Answer (score -1):

Офигеть! Уже Змей Горыныч из евреев… А чуть подробней, пожалуйста…

Горыня, Дубыня и Усыня – мифологическая персофиникация природных стихий (огонь, вода, земля). На данном этапе попытки определиться с началом имен не играет роли, какой стихией кто повелевал. Интересно другое. Змей Горыныч тоже ведь о трех головах, а значит можно предположить, что каждая голова также относится к определенной стихии. Гореть '*огонь*' и Гора '*земля*' уже были озвучены. Что характерно: обе стихии включают консонант ГР и могут сочетаться друг с другом – Вулкан, как божество огня, так и "огненная гора" в "натуре". Предлагаю свою версию головы-"воды", удовлетворяющей тем же условиям - Гроза. Это и "огненная вода" (не путать с алкоголем) и консонант ГР. Варианта сочетания земли воды от меня не будет, да и в одной из мифологий они попросту разъеденены. Хотя почему не будет – ГРЯЗЬ, ГРУДА (в том значении, которым этимологируется месяц *грудень*).

А посему: персонаж богатырь Горыня явление более позднее, чем Змей Горыныч. Но свое "отчество" Змей мог получить и от Горыни, как, допустим, по утрате/забвении исконного имени, так и по причинам благозвучия, так и по изменению вероопределенности. Во всяком случае, этимологическими приемами вглубь истории имени Змея Горыныча далее не протиснуться. Однако есть одно "но"…

Этимология, как наука, вышла из философии, потому обратиться к истокам философии будет приемом хоть и необычным, но правильным, ну а там... Стихии от греческого слова στοίχος, одно из значений которого – ‘*буква*’. Надо заметить, что становление философии и появление "нового греческого алфавита" – процессы параллельные. Иначе: греки так восхитились неким новым алфавитом, что первые свои философские труды посвятили этим самым "стихиям-буквам". А вот финикийский, да и сам греческий алфавиты на роль этого первоисточника стихий не годятся. Именно там, в стихиях-буквах и может скрываться древнее имя нашего Змея.

Ну что, товарищи профессионалы, поможете понять настоящее имя Змея Горыныча? Нужно очень…